# Constant of integration in $s'(t)=A\cos{2t}$?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

For $s'(t)=\cos{2t}$ I have the solution $s(t)+C_1=\frac{1}{2}\sin{2t}+C_2$, i.e. $s(t)=\frac{1}{2}\sin{2t}+C_3$, where $C_3=C_2-C_1$.
However, say I have an extra constant $A$ in the function, is the following correct:
$$
s'(t)=A\cos{2t}
$$
Gives
$$
s(t)+C_1=A\big (\frac{1}{2}\sin{2t}+C_2\big )=A\frac{1}{2}\sin{2t}+AC_2
$$
So
$$
s(t)=A\frac{1}{2}\sin{2t}+AC_2-C_1=A\frac{1}{2}\sin{2t}+C_3,
$$
where $C_3=AC_2-C_1$?

Is it also correct regardless if $A$ is positive or negative?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. All of $C_1, C_2, A$ are constants. You can add, subtract, multiply and divide ($\neq0$) constants and the result would also be a constant

Answer (score 1):

Yes, $A $ is a constant, $C_1, C_2$ are also constants.

Hence, $$\text { Constant } \times \text { Constant } - \text{ Constant} = \text { Another constant } $$

It doesn't depend on the sign of $A $, **of course**, you will get definitely different values, but $C_3$ is still a constant.